# Pocketsphinx not installing

Tags: python-2.7, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have downloaded Pocketsphinx from https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx but is unable to understand how to load .sln files since, i have never used visual studio.. currently i am using visual studio 2012.

I even tried downloading from https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python even after installing all the dependencies i am facing with error :

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open incl ude file: 'stdint.h': No such file
>   or directory error: command
>   'C:\Users\deamons\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\
>   \Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status
>   2

Comment: You can download prebuilt binary here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/pocketsphinx-5prealpha-win32.zip/download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to
https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/issues/18 and
https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python/issues/9
it should be fixed now (there was unnecessary include for stdint.h), please update your local git repo.